# IIFE in Swift Language

Tags: swift, iife

In javascript we use IIFEs a lot. Something like

```
(function() {
    ...do stuff to avoid dirtying scope.
}());
```

There are closures in Swift, and functions are first class objects. My question is: are there equivalent IIFEs in Swift?

Comment: You can almost certainly create a closure and invoke it immediately in Swift. But that may not be idiomatic, if Swift has a less roundabout way of introducing a new scope. Do you want the former or the latter?

Comment: IIFEs are used because ECMAScript only has global and function scope. They aren't necessary in most other languages. For example, in JavaScript, a variable in a loop is shared by all iterations of the loop and all the code outside the loop. In Swift and most other languages, loop-local variables are actually scoped inside the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve a similar effect using closures, sure:

```
func iife( f : () -> () ) {
 f()
}
```

And then say

```
iffe { 
// my code here
}
```

If all you truly need is a scope, while Swift does not support the use of {..} as a "scoping operator", you can always do

```
if 1 == 1 {
// oh, look, a scope :-)
}
```

as a less fancy way to achieve the same effect.
If you're trying to use RAII patterns, you will need to either rely on ARC to cleanup for you, or use a closure though

```
if true {
    // should also work instead of if 1 == 1
}
```

Comment: Control-flow constructs (e.g. loops and conditionals) are pretty much the only reason you'd ever want to introduce a new scope in the middle of a function, and they already do so themselves in Swift. I don't think there is any point do doing `if 1 == 1`.

Comment: Swift already has a immediately-invoke closure syntax that's just as concise as your `iffe` helper and more closely matches the syntax in JavaScript and other languages (with a trailing `()`).  Helper functions are great when they add value to the codebase, but for this it's really best to just use the built-in syntax for code readability/understandability.

Answer (score 12):

The accepted answer here is misleading—there's an easier and more elegant manner in which to create an immediately-invoked closure expression (IICE).

For all of the details and variances of syntax, see the [Apple Swift Documentation for closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID97). For a simple demo, see this:

```
let dateString: NSString = { date in
  let timestampFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

  timestampFormatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
  timestampFormatter.timeStyle = .MediumStyle

  return timestampFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
}(NSDate())
```

[image]

Comment: This is indeed the best way to do it. The simplest version of that would be: `{}()` (which returns Void). By contrast, the simplest JS version possible is `(() => {})()` (which returns undefined). I love that this ultra-light syntax is possible at all in a strongly-typed language like Swift!

Answer (score 4):

Here's another example of a Swift immediately-invoked closure expression (IICE) - which I pronounce as "Icky" (in a nod to JavaScript's IIFE, which is pronounced "Iffy" - http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

```
var player:AVAudioPlayer = {
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sound1", ofType: "mp3")!
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        let p = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url as URL)
        p.volume = 0.3
        p.prepareToPlay()
        return p
    }()
```

And if you use the `lazy` modifier, you are then allowed to access `self`.

From the Swift Language Guide: "Lazy properties are useful when the initial value for a property is dependent on outside factors whose values are not known until after an instance’s initialization is complete. Lazy properties are also useful when the initial value for a property requires complex or computationally expensive setup that should not be performed unless or until it is needed."

```
let startVolume:Float = 0.3
lazy var player:AVAudioPlayer = {
       let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sound1", ofType: "mp3")!
       let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
       let p = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url as URL)
       p.volume = self.startVolume
       p.prepareToPlay()
       return p
  }()
```

Also see "Setting a Default Property Value with a Closure or Function" in the Swift Language Guide.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```swift
({
    /* Code here */
}()) == ()
```

Or this?

```swift
({
    print("hi")
}()).self
```

Or this from JS?

```swift
({
    print("hi")
}())
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found uses for immediately invoked closures in swift when I want one-time execution of code to initialize a property.  For instance:

```
class MyClass {
    //One time initialization of managedObjectContext property
    lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = { () -> NSManagedObjectContext in
        let context = NSManagedObjectContext()
        //do all the initial setup, etc...
        return context
    }()

    //more stuff...
}
```

There are other ways to achieve the same thing, but I found this to be a nice pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in `do {}` without `catch`

```
do {
  // local scope
  let x = 10
  print(x)
}

// global scope
let x = "string"
print(x)
```